# What does this symbol mean (looks like ><)?

Tags: optimization, notation, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I'm currently looking at notes on Linear Optimisation and have come across a symbol in the context of formulating a LO problem that looks like this $^{>}{}_<$ but I can't tell what it is supposed to mean.
My best guess is that it is supposed to mean $x_j < 0$ or has some relation to the absolute value.

The link to the pdf I'm looking at is: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-093j-optimization-methods-fall-2009/8d61040c41eefd68dda84ce05d82ad71_MIT15_093J_F09_lec02.pdf

Would be grateful for any help with this!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the surrounding context I think it means "$x_j$ could be bigger or smaller than 0"

[image: From Section 2.2]

In the *standard form* of a LP, the variables are nonnegative ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) for an example). So this notation is likely chosen to emphasize that these $x_j$ variables (from the set $N_2$, see below image) could be positive or negative.

[image]

Then, the document shows how you can use auxiliary variables and add extra constraints in order to turn this into a standard form LP (where all the variables $x_j^+, x_j^-$ are nonnegative).

Comment: Just to be clear, $x_j$ could equal zero as well, right?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, because when you split into positive and negative parts you could have $x_j^+ = x_j^- = 0$. Which makes the symbol chosen particularly awful. This notation is definitely nonstandard, I'd avoid using it outside of this particular course

Comment: Thanks for your help! Hope you don't mind me asking but, is it also correct of me to assume that $x_j^{+} = max(0, x_j)$ and $x_j^{-} = min(0, x_j)$ ?

Comment: No, $x_j^- \geq 0$, so you would have $x_j^- = -\min(0, x_j)$